# store data in an array using getc()

Tags: arrays, c

is there any way to store data in an array from a file using `getc()` function, not `fscanf()`?

For example, there is a file "file.txt" containing following data:

```
Name
Surname
Age
```

So the content of the array arr[] would be:

```
arr[] = {Name, Surname, Age}
```

So far I could only print out the content of the file to the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    while (((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) )
    {
        putc(ch, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It was a requirement of the assignment that libraries other than stdio.h cannot be used. I can easily do it with `fscanf()` but `getc()` function creates some not some difficulties.

Comment: `fscanf()` is part of `stdio.h`.

Comment: Yeah, but prof made it clear that fscanf() is forbidden to use :(

Comment: If you know how to do it with `fscanf`, write a program using it and test it. Once it successfuly works, just replace the `fscanf` call by a call to a custom function using `getc` and returning new line delimited strings.

Comment: "libraries other than stdio.h" I assume, the real quote was "library functions other than those declared in stdio.h". Otherwise it would create the impression, "stdio.h" might be a library which it isn't. It is just a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to store data in an array from a file using `getc()` function, not `fscanf()`?

Yes. By reading and assigning values to an element of an array, and increasing the index for each character. Repeat this until a newline character is found, or the file is exhausted.

Make sure to leave room for the null-terminating byte (`\0'`) in order to create a [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), by placing one after the last character read.

A quick alteration to your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "file.txt"
#define MAXSIZE 128

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    FILE *file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    
    if (!file) {
        perror(FILENAME);
        return 1;
    }

    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;
    char array[MAXSIZE];

    while (i < MAXSIZE - 1 && ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF)) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;

        array[i++] = ch;
    }

    /* null-terminate the array to create a string */
    array[i] = '\0';

    fclose(file);

    puts(array);
}
```

If you extract this logic into its own function, that accepts an array to fill, a character limit, and the file to read from, and you will have largely recreated [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: How can I read the next string in a file using this? Should I make my array 2D? So, the first subscribe would be line number and the next subscribe would be characters?

Comment: Yup, that's one way to do it (a 2D array matches your description of `arr[] = {Name, Surname, Age}`). You'll need to watch out that you don't try to read too many lines (in addition to not reading too many characters per line).