# Array and file I/O

Tags: arrays, c

I have following data in a file:

```
Name 
Surname
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILENAME "file.txt"
#define MAXSIZE 128
int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    FILE *file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror(FILENAME);
        return 1;
    }

    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;
    char array[3][MAXSIZE];
    for(int a=0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        while (i < MAXSIZE - 1 && ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF))
        {
            if (ch == '\n')
                break;
            
            array[a][i++] = ch;
        }
    /* null-terminate the array to create a string */
        array[a][i] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(file);
    for(int a=0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", array[a][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program it gives me output like this [image]"

How can I modify it, so it will not output garbage?
This is a link to my previous post:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349412/store-data-in-an-array-using-getc)

Comment: Your printing loop `for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { printf("%c", array[a][i]); }` needs to stop when `array[a][i] == '\0'` —— add `if (array[a][i] == '\0') break;` before the `printf()`.  You also need to reset `i` to `0` before the `while` loop (but after the `for` loop.  If you declared `i` inside the first `for` loop, you'd not have the problems you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355359/array-and-file-i-o#comment131267328_74355359):

> - Your printing loop `for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { printf("%c", array[a][i]); }` needs to stop when `array[a][i] == '\0'` —— add `if (array[a][i] == '\0') break;` before the `printf()`.
> - You also need to reset `i` to 0 before the while loop (but after the `for` loop). If you declared `i` inside the first for loop, you'd not have the problems you do.

Note that you have two different variables called `i` (one is `size_t i = 0;` before the loops; the other is `for (int i = 0; …)` while printing) and one hides the other.  That can lead to confusion.

Those changes might lead to this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "file.txt"
#define MAXSIZE 128

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    FILE *file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror(FILENAME);
        return 1;
    }

    char array[3][MAXSIZE];
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        int ch;
        size_t i = 0;
        while (i < MAXSIZE - 1 && ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF))
        {
            if (ch == '\n')
                break;            
            array[a][i++] = ch;
        }
        array[a][i] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(file);
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (array[a][i] == '\0')
                break;
            printf("%c", array[a][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

There's also no obvious reason not to print the data using:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    puts(array[a]);
```

or

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    printf("%s\n", array[a]);
```